# distance between std::set begin() and std::set iterator in O(logn)

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set, std

I need to find the index of an element in std::set. This index can be visualized as the distance of the iterator from the beginning.
One way can be:

```
for(int i = 0, set<int>::iterator it = s.begin(); it != iteratorToBeFound; ++it, ++i);
```

This clearly takes O(n) time. But we know that the distance from the root in a binary search tree as implemented by set internally can be found in O(log n) time.

Is their any way to implement the same to find the index in O(log n) time in C++ set?

Comment: Why would you need the index?

Comment: Are you sure that it's possible to find the distance in `O(log n)` time in a binary search tree? `set` is typically a red-black tree, which doesn't have a lot of information at each node about how many elements are in its left and right subtrees respectively. Remember that you're not looking for the distance directly from the root, you're looking for the total number of leaves to the left of the leaf you have.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Ohh, so their isn't any way to calculate the index in O(logn) in R-B tree then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sorted `std::vector<int>`. If it is sorted, you can find element in `O(log n)`. And you can find distance in constant time `O(1)`.

By sorted vector I mean that after every insertion (or after many insertions) you do `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());`

If your type inside `std::set<T>` is not as light like `int` - you can keep both - `std::set<T>` and sorted vector of iterators `std::vector<std::set<T>::iterator>`. But it could not trivial to keep these structures in sync. Maybe you can add some like position to `T`? Or keep `std::set<std::pair<T,int>, comp_first_of_pair<T>>` where `comp_first_of_pair` is just to have `set` sorted only by `T` and the second `int` is for keeping position in set?

Just a few ideas - to have even `O(1)` distance time...

Comment: But sorting after every insertion in std::vector would cost me O(nlogn). Where's the advantage?

Comment: 1) You can sort only after a series of consecutive insertions. 2) Cost of insertion in `std::set<>` is `O(log n)` - n insertions: `O(n Log n)`. 3) Maybe you `insert` once - but testing distance many times....

Answer (score 6):

You can use the function [`std::set<>::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) to search for an element `x` and compute the [distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) to the first iterator of the set.

```
std::distance(s.begin(), s.find(x))
```

However, as comments indicate the runtime of distance depends on the type of iterator used. In the case of a set this is a bidirectional iterator and distance is O(n).

Comment: That's `O(log n + m)`, though. But the best you can do, AFAIK.

Comment: But [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) is O(N) here.

Comment: I know about std::distance but this is implemented the same way as written in the question and definitely is O(n).

Answer (score 4):

You can find the index of an element in a set in O(log(N)) with an ordered set: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ordered-set-gnu-c-pbds/ . This is implemented as a red-black tree. I know this topic is very old, but it might help readers in the future.

Comment: Rather than link to an external resource, please excerpt the relevant portion of it and include it in your answer.

Comment: Very good code, and I could solve one problem I had where the bottleneck was `std::set`'s `distance` being O(N). This worked like magic!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use matematics with bidirectional iterators. So only acceptable way is to count by yourself (how many **int** less than X you inserted into set).

But, if you have cleanly separated "data collection" and "data usage" stages - probably it is worth to replace **std::set** with sorted **std::vector**. Its harder to maintain, but have own benefits, including iterator matematics (so you can get search with O(log n) with **std::binary_search** and the distance with O(1) )

Answer (score 1):

If computing the index is **really** your bottleneck, then I see 2 options:

- Store the index. Either in the nodes themselves or in a separate `std::map`.
  Of course this means you have to keep this cache updated.
- Use a `std::vector`. That is not as bad as it might look at first.
  If you keep the vector always sorted you can use it like a `set`.
  The performance will be similar to `set`.
  The biggest drawback is: the node might be copied a lot.
  (This can be compensated by using pointers, `boost:shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` [c++11 only])

  To look up an element you use `std::lower_bound`. 
  Instead of insert/push_back you do: `insert( lower_bound(b,e,x), x )`

Comment: insert is a O(n) function in vector

Comment: And remember to use specialized version of lower_bound for containers that implements it. Newer use std::lower_bound for ordered (multi)map and (multi)sets